# Lambda: How to iterate /loop through the SNS topics to get all Topic Attributes?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sns

I'm writing a custom config rule for AWS SNS and want to iterate through all the topics. I'm able to get all the topics by using `.list_topics()` but not able to loop through these topics to get attributes of each topic.
Currently, I'm able to fetch the SNS topic attribute of the only first 
`topic_arn = response["Topics"][0]['TopicArn']`

I want to fetch SNS topic attributes from all the topics listed and can think of for loop? How to for loop topic?

```
def get_all_topics(sns_client):
  sns_client = boto3.client('sns')
  response = sns_client.list_topics()
  topics = [topic['TopicArn'] for topic in response['Topics']]
  print("Topic List: %s" % topics)
  return topics

'''
Fetch SNS Topic attributes
'''
def get_topic_attributes():
  sns_client = boto3.client('sns')
  response = sns_client.list_topics()
  topic_arn = response["Topics"][0]['TopicArn']
  response_topic_attribute_dict = sns_client.get_topic_attributes(TopicArn=topic_arn)
  print("SNS Topic attributes: %s" % response_topic_attribute_dict)
  return response_topic_attribute_dict
```

'''
Test SNS For Loop which gives an error
'''

```
def evaluate_compliance():
  sns_client = boto3.client('sns')
  response = sns_client.list_topics()
  topics = [topic['TopicArn'] for topic in response['Topics']]
  for topic_dict in topics:
      response = sns_client.list_topics()
      response_topic_attributes_dict = sns_client.get_topic_attributes(TopicArn=topic_dict['TopicArn'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my test code. The definition of the boto3 session might different but you can ignore.

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session(region_name='ap-northeast-2')
client = session.client('sns')

response = client.list_topics()
for item in response['Topics']:
    print(item['TopicArn'])
```

OR

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session(region_name='ap-northeast-2')
sns = session.resource('sns')

for topic in sns.topics.all():
    print(topic.arn)
```

The result is:

```
arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-2:1...3:2...
arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-2:1...3:A...
arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-2:1...3:A...
arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-2:1...3:A...
arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-2:1...3:A...
arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-2:1...3:A...
arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-2:1...3:A...
arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-2:1...3:B...
arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-2:1...3:B...
arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-2:1...3:B...
arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-2:1...3:B...
```

---

By continuing with this code, you can obtain the attributes for all topics such as:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session(region_name='ap-northeast-2')
client = session.client('sns')

response = client.list_topics()
for item in response['Topics']:
    print(item['TopicArn'])
    print(client.get_topic_attributes(TopicArn=item['TopicArn']))
```

Comment: Thanks but your code above only prints all the TopicArn's. How do you get topic attributes from all the Topics? In my code, I'm able to get attributes for only one topic .    
   `topic_arn = response["Topics"][0]['TopicArn']
  response_topic_attribute_dict = sns_client.get_topic_attributes(TopicArn=topic_arn)`